# jquery javascript find how far left an element is with position:relative

Tags: jquery, css, position

in jquery/javascript I'm trying to find how far left an element is with position:relative.  There are several elements between this one and the left of the screen.  since it is positioned:relative and float:left using:

```
 $(this).css('left');
```

gives me '0px' every time.  So how do I found how far the element is from the left of the screen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.offset()` method.

**Here's an example:** http://jsfiddle.net/PgbmV/

```
$(this).offset().left;
```

- http://api.jquery.com/offset/

This will give the left position relative to the document.

If you want the position relative to its container, you would use `.position()` in a similar manner.

```
$(this).position().left;
```

- http://api.jquery.com/position/